# Javascript dropdownlist value is not getting selected value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist` which is binded from the database. But on modification it loses its value.

Here is what I write to get value in the list.

```
if (document.getElementById('GrdDamagedstock_tplRowEdit_ctl00_cmbFromBin').value == "") {
    var FindItemCode = document.getElementById('Hid_FromBin').value;
    var ddl = document.getElementById('GrdDamagedstock_tplRowEdit_ctl00_cmbFromBin');
    for(var i=0; i<ddl.options.length; i++) {
        if (ddl.options[i].text === FindItemCode) {
            ddl.selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not getting dropdown filled

**NOTE** : It just doesn't goes inside `for (var j = 0; i < ddl.options.length; j++) {`

Comment: Make sure your `ddl` have at least one option to get into loop

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja: yes it one option.

Comment: Since your options are filled by `server`, There may be some latency. `log` the `ddl.options.length` before `for loop` to confirm that `select` have `options`

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja: I log and got value as `0`. why ? But I have `--select--` in that list.

Comment: This is the issue of latency, your `JS` running before server filling the `options`. Wrap your `js` inside any `onload` function

Comment: can u show with code, Also, I want to fill this on edit of the grid row

Comment: Are you using `jQuery` ? Once follow the answer below writing script after `body` tag.

Comment: No. its javascript..can u suggest and if possible come on chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133515/discussion-between-nad-and-jyothi-babu-araja).

Answer (score 0):

you can replace that for loop with the following code:

```
$('#GrdDamagedstock_tplRowEdit_ctl00_cmbFromBin > option').each(function(){
     if(this.text == FindItemCode){
          $('#GrdDamagedstock_tplRowEdit_ctl00_cmbFromBin').val(this.value);
          break;
     }
});
```

Comment: can you let me know that how it will be invalid